# Handling multiple view in backbone on page load

Tags: backbone.js, view

Right now i have one backbone view in which i have some forms, each form corresponds to one model, Once i get the data from server using ajax, i am rendering this one view. problem with this approach is when any single model changes entire view needs to re render, i want to render only that view corresponding to the model.

Problem: I want to break this view in multiple views, each view will have one model corresponding to that form. I can do that no problem but how can i render these views on page load, one after other like below?

view1.render(); view2.render();...viewN.render();

want to ask if this is good approach? are they async by default?

Answer (score 0):

Look into [Marionette.js](http://marionettejs.com/) and the [collection view](http://marionettejs.com/docs/v2.4.1/marionette.collectionview.html).